# Must graduate applicants who will need funding submit financial statement for I-20?

Tags: application, funding, united-states, international-students, visa

[image]

I am applying this time for graduate admission in physics at Utah.  In the online application they require a financial statement.  Does graduate admission require it too, even though I must need a TA/RA?

Answer (score 10):

A financial statement is required by the US for visa eligibility for *all* international students applying for standard student visas. It is not needed for admissions decisions, as stated in the form you've uploaded.

The purpose of the statement is to show that you will be able to support yourself (and any dependents) while you are in the US. If the university offers funding, you will use that as a source of support on your I-20. If the university funding does not fully meet all your financial requirements, then you will need to show that you can handle the rest of your expenses through other sources.

You don't need to worry about the I-20 until after you've been admitted. The university will give you more information then, including how to submit the necessary documents and what the official program expenses are for visa purposes.

Answer (score 3):

When I applied, I emailed and asked about the financial statement for the one university that required it (Ohio State), and they told me to upload a document stating basically:

Personal funds: 0$

From university: (Tuition + standard stipend for the given program)$

I suggest emailing them and asking what they prefer you to do.